# postgresql: import date from csv in mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to import the .csv file through pgAdmin 4

In a table, I have a column, format `date`

In the .csv file, I have a date in format `05/31/1990`

date style is `MDY`

but I still have an error: value is out of range `05/31/1990`

there are a lot of rows in my file and I can't just change them in my file manually

any ideas?

Comment: Look at the answer here, this might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722997/1156233

Comment: How are determining the `DateStyle` is `MDY`.? As `show datestyle ; ISO, MDY, select '05/31/1990'::date; 1990-05-31` then `SET DateStyle = "ISO, DMY"; select '05/31/1990'::date; ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "05/31/1990"`. To me it looks like your `DateStyle` is actually `DMY`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ```show datestyle``` output is ```ISO, MDY``` and ```select '05/31/1990'::date;``` gives out ```1990-05-31```. When I try to add dates manualy, it's okay, but it seems to drop my datestyle when it comes to import

Comment: How are you importing the CSV through pgAdmin4?